# How do I construct an ElasticSearch search using NEST with fields from multiple types without magic strings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm setting up a system where my search indexed objects are Entities which map back to a normalized SQL database. So on the SQL side I may have a `Company` which is linked to one or more `Company_Address` records, as well as `Company_Email` records, etc. But all of the relevant searchable fields will be in a single `Company` indexed document tying back to the `Company`'s unique id field.

I'm trying to setup queries which will return the relevant id based on comparing a user provided query string with specific fields in the indexed document. I can do so with a query similar to:

```
var searchResponse = this.client.Search<Company>(search => search.Query(
    s => s.MultiMatch(
        m => m.Query(query.QueryString)
            .Fields(f => f.Field(c => c.Name).Field("Address1")) // Magic strings go here
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
        )).Index<Company>());
```

I'd like to be able to replace "Address1" with `ca.Address1` where ca is a CompanyAddress object. Is there a way to construct a collection of FieldDescriptor objects with multiple backing types and then supply that to the search query?

Comment: `Address1` property also exists on the `Company` type that maps to documents in Elasticsearch too?

Comment: No. The Address1 property exists on a `CompanyAddress` type in my code.  However, it is a Field in the `Company` Document which is stored in Elasticsearch.

Comment: OK, but NEST will deserialize the json `_source` returned from Elasticsearch into instances of `Company` as specified in the `Search<T>` call, so `Address1` field values will not be assigned to any property on `Company`

Comment: Correct. The documents we're storing in Elastic aren't 1 to 1 mappings with our POCO objects. They're amalgamations of the searchable fields from multiple linked objects. I'm using a source filter to exclude most of the data which comes back from Elastic and only keeping the `id` values. Those `id` values are then used to map back 1 to 1 with strongly typed entities in our SQL database.

Comment: I see. Just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a `Fields` instance in a number of ways:

1. Building a `Fields` instance by chaining `Field` instances, constructing those from member access Lambda expressions on some type `T`

   ```
       var searchResponse = this.client.Search<Company>(search => search
           .Query(q => q
               .MultiMatch(m => m
                   .Query("query")
                   .Fields(
                       Infer.Field<Company>(c => c.Name)
                       .And<CompanyAddress>(c => c.Address1)
                   )
                   .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
               )
           )
           .Index<Company>()
       );
   ```
2. Using [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) with the `Address1` property of `CompanyAddress`

   ```
   var searchResponse = this.client.Search<Company>(search => search
       .Query(q => q
           .MultiMatch(m => m
               .Query(query.QueryString)
               .Fields(f => f
                   .Field(c => c.Name)
                   .Field(nameof(CompanyAddress.Address1))
               )
               .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
           )
       )
       .Index<Company>()
   );
   ```